# Getting "Heap Corruption Detected: after Normal block" when freeing memory

Tags: c++

I just wanna test memory allocation and deletion by following code:

```
char* t = new char[20]();
char* t2 = t + 22;
*t2 = 0x01;
printf("I am here\n");
delete[] t;
```

First, at "char* t2 = t + 22;" I know that I might be accessing to an invalid memory slot. However, just for testing, I still do that. In many lucky cases, I have got no error at "*t2 = 0x01;". But "delete[] t;" always raises "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#56)" error. Why is that?

NOTE: My concern is that why it does not raise exception right after "*t2 = 0x01;"? Why it has to wait until "delete[] t;"?

Comment: Because you corrupted the heap.  That's like asking, "I drove through a red light, and hit another car.  Why did I hit the car?"

Comment: @OldProgrammer But why it does not raise exception right after *t = 0x01?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined behavior is undefined - anything can happen.

In this case the specific thing that most likely happened is the heap manager over-allocated you `t` and put sentinel bytes after your allocated memory. When you freed the memory it checked those sentinel bytes and as they had changed it flagged heap corruption.

Comment: My concern is that why it does not raise exception right after "*t2 = 0x01;"? Why it has to wait until "delete[] t;"?

Comment: @duong_dajgja Because none of the memory manager's code is running at that point? It also doesn't go through the whole heap checking for problems constantly, as that would be really inefficient.